# Update WYGWAM's CKEditor manually

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, ckeditor

After the Safari-7.1-Update the CKEditor does no more work properly. There is a fix: [CKEditor 4.4.5 with Safari 7.1 Fix Released](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.4.5-Released)

Which packet do I have to download (Basic, Standard, Full) and where do I have to install it?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor goes through a build process when being integrated into Wygwam adding some custom stuff.  It's not a matter of a simple swap out.

We will have to update Wygwam's CKEditor version in the next Wygwam release.

Comment: thanks, brad; when do you think will the update be delivered?for me there is the problem that I urgently need the wygwam-functionality for the backend. do you perhaps know a workaround how to update the ckeditor manually?

Comment: Sorry... I don't have an ETA, but we're due for a new Wygwam update.  And I'm not aware of any workarounds.

Comment: Hi Brad, is there any vision when the update will be published? For Safari-Users it's a real mess, and there are some which have serious problems understanding that they now have to switch browsers because something they have paid for is not working anymore correctly ...

Comment: Brad, I am still waiting for the update. It's really annoying, to be honest. As I told I also would be satisfied with a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ... I tried this: Downloaded the Basic Package and replaced in
themes/third_party/wygwam/lib the folder ckeditor.

This seems to work.

UPDATE: It does not work. A lot of unexpected occurrences. Would be glad if somebody could help me out :-/

Comment: You might want to reach out to Pixel and Tonic as this fix could get rolled into a new update for WYGWAM and would benefit other users too.

Comment: done, see answer from p&t above - thanks :-)